# Can we not using the one hot user feature when training the factorization machine?

Tags: recommendation-engine, factorization

Now I have `n` users and `k` total items, for each user, he has bought some items, and I want to train a FM on the existing users/items dataset, with which I will be able to recommend new items to a new user who has already got some items.

What if I arrange my feature X as,

```
    items        all items        y
0 ... 1 ... 0  1, 0, ..., 1, 0    1

    items        all items        y
0 ... 0 ... 1  1, 0, ..., 1, 0    0
```

therefore when predicting for the new user, I don't need to find the user that is most similar to the new user in training dataset and recommend for the old user instead.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, these sparse features are **useful** for **memorization**, especially 1st order feautre. Of course, we can also use field embedding layer to convert these onehot features to dense features, before applying other structures, like DNN, PNN, etc.